# How to access the req object from an Actions2 function in SailsJS?

Tags: sails.js

I want to use my session information from a SailsJS standalone action ( from a controller I use req.session.`<session variable name>`)

But from a stand alone action ( Actions2 ) you don't define the functions with (req, res), but instead with (inputs, exits).

Answer (score 3):

NeoNexus DeMortis Is correct, I just came across this and thought I could offer an alternative. Sails uses a module called machine-as-action that allows you to access the request object without passing `env` into the function. Without passing in `env` you can access req and res functions by calling `this.req` or `this.res`.

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/actions-and-controllers#actions2

Also, to my knowledge, the only reason to use res with actions2 is to set a custom response header (this.res.set('Name-Of-Header', 'whatever value you want for header'))-- or one of the convenience methods like this.res.type('image/png')  which tells the user agent (e.g. browser) how to process the download.
Same thing for whatever the method is to set the "content disposition" (which just means whether or not you want to instruct the browser to try to open it in-browser (which it might or might not do, depending on its capabilities) or always encourage it to skip even trying to open it at all and always just doing "save file as", even if it's something it could have opened itself, like a PDF)

Comment: I don't recommend using `res` in Actions2 functions, as that defeats the purpose of `exits`. Generally speaking, it's better to use custom responses to change content types, so they can be reused by other actions.

Answer (score 2):

Hello @Arturo welcome to SO!

This is a perplexing problem, as I can't remember now how I figured it out, because I can't seem to find documentation for this (I believe I went through the source code to find it). But, there is an "escape hatch" in Actions2 functions, a third parameter you can add, `env`. So, you have `inputs, exits, env` for your function signature; inside `env` is `req` and `res`.

Here is an example of using `req` to pass around `session` data: https://github.com/neonexus/sails-react-bootstrap-webpack/blob/release/api/controllers/common/get-me.js

I'm using the `isLoggedIn` policy to populate the `session` in `req`, as I'm handling things a bit more manually, so I can use Sails' built-in models; seen here: https://github.com/neonexus/sails-react-bootstrap-webpack/blob/release/api/policies/isLoggedIn.js

Comment: I'm currently using this solution. Thanks !